# Displaying columns form a table on a webapage in Django

Tags: django

I need to display a table from my database using only certain columns. In my view I have this:

```
def home_page(request):
    query_results = Model.objects.filter(open=True)
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

and my `home.html` page looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th>Column2</th>
  </tr>
  {% for item in query_results %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ item.col1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.col2 }}</td>
  <tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

However, when I go to the page, there isn't any data in the table. Am I going about this wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also you didn't include `query_results` to the context. Try this: `return render(request, 'home.html', {'query_results': query_results})`

Comment: @neverwalkaloner, Thank you, that seemed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to include `query_results` to the template context. Try this:

```
return render(request, 'home.html', {'query_results': query_results})
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your answer, it worked perfectly. Also, I dig your profile picture ;)